# Angular create two cookies with same name and diff path

Tags: angularjs, cookies

Im using cookie in two difference controllers ,but it is doesnt rewrite value and create a new one,so i have two cookies with same name and difference path.How can i make to rewrite it?

Comment: First check if value exists in cookie, if exists then delete first and set.

Comment: How do you create cookies? Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie